# Is it wrong to switch client logic in the service tier?

Tags: soa

We have two client apps (a web app and an agent app) accessing methods on the same service, but with slightly different requirements.  My team wants to control behaviour on the service side by passing in a ApplicationType parameter to every method - which is essentially an enum containing the name of the calling client application - which is then used as a key for a database lookup to configure the service with client-specific options.

Something about this makes me uneasy as I don't think the service should really have to be aware of which client is calling it.  I'm being told that it's easier to do it this way than pass a load of options dynamically through the method call.

Is there anything wrong with the client application telling the service who they are?  Or is there really no difference between passing a config key versus a set of parameterized options?

One immediate problem I can see is that if we ever opened the service to another client run by a third party, we'd have to maintain their configuration settings locally for them.  At the moment we own both client apps so it's not so much of a problem.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 3):

In a layered solution, you should always consider your layers as onion-like layers, and dependencies should always go inwards, never outwards.

So your GUI/App layer should depend on the businesslogic layer, the businesslogic layer should depend on the data access layer, and similar.

Unless you categorize the clients (web, win, wpf, cli), or generalize it with client profiles (which client applications can configure), I would never pass in the name of the calling application, as this would make the business logic layer aware of and dependent upon the outside layer.

What kind of differences are we talking about that would depend on the type of application? If you elaborate a bit on the differences here, perhaps someone can come up with some helpful advice on other ways to solve this.

But I would definitely look for other ways before going down your described path.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you create two different services, one for each application? The two services will share a lot of code or call a single internal service with different parameterization depending on what outer service was called.

Answer (score 0):

From a design perspective, this is no different than having users with different profiles.  From a security perspective, I hope your applications are doing something to identify themselves, lest users of one application figure out a way to invoke the other applications logic as a hack. (Image a HR application being used by the mafia and a bank at the same time, one customer would be interesting in hacking the other customer's application on a shared application host)

In .net the design doesn't feel this way because the credentials live on the thread (i.e. when you set the IIPrincipal, that info rides on the thread-- it is communicated along with each method call, but not as a parameter.)

Maybe what you are looking for in terms of a more elegant design is an ApplicationIdentity attribute.  You'd have to write a custom one, I don't know of one in the framework right now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard topic to discuss without a solid example.

You are right for feeling that way.  Sending in the client type to change behaviour is not correct.  It's not a bad idea for logging... but that's about it.

Here is what I would do:

- Review each method to see what needs to be different and why.
- Create different methods for different usages.  The method name should be self explanatory.  If you ever need to break compatibility, you have more control (assuming you're not using a versioning system which would be overkill for an in-house-only service).
- In some cases request parameters (flags/enum values) are more appropriate.
- In some cases knowing the operating environment is more appropriate (especially for data security).  The operating environment almost always sent during a login request.  Something like "attended"/"secure" (agent client) vs "unattended"/"not secure" (web client).  Now you must exchange a session key (HTTP cookie or an application level session id).  Sessions obviously doesn't work if you need to be 100% stateless -- especially if you want to scale-out without session replication... if you have that requirement, send a structure in every request.

Think of requests like functions in your code.  You wouldn't put a magic parameter that changes the behaviour of the function.  You would create multiple functions that each behave differently.  Whoever is using the function makes the decision which one to call.

So why is client type so wrong?  Client type has no specific meaning on its own.  It has many meanings and they may change over time.  It's simply informational which is why it is a handy thing to log.  An operating environment does have a specific meaning.

Here is a scenario to consider: What if a new client type is developed that is slightly different in a way that would break compatibility with the original request?  Now you have two requests.  2 clients use Request A and 1 client uses Request B.  If you pass in a client type to each request, the server is expected to work for every possible client type.  Much harder to test and maintain!!